# CakePHP 3 - How to load components

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2 you could specify which components to load in the controller by providing a `$components` property.

```
class AppController extends Controller
{

    public $components = [
        'RequestHandler',
        'Security'
    ];
}
```

I notice this still works in CakePHP 3 but that most of the book uses a new method in which you load every component separately:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Security');
}
```

Is the `$components` property provided only for backwards compatibility? I want to do it the correct Cake 3 way, especially if the former method will be deprecated at some point in the future.

---

**Are there any differences in functionality between the two methods?**

If I try to configure the SecurityComponent like this, it doesn't work and the configuration seems to be completely ignored, even though it's a valid use of the method:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Security', ['blackHoleCallback', 'blackhole']);
}
```

Instead, I have to make a separate method call in `beforeFilter()` to set the configuration and get it to actually work:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Security');
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Security->config('blackHoleCallback', 'blackhole');
}
```

However, the old 'Cake 2' way still works fine:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{

    public $components = [
        'RequestHandler',
        'Security' => ['blackHoleCallback' => 'blackhole']
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the $components property provided only for backwards compatibility? I want to do it the correct Cake 3 way, especially if the former method will be deprecated at some point in the future.

It's not yet deprecated [as you can see here](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#171-183). But loading it via the method call is the better way of doing it. I guess the property is going to be dropped in 4.x and maybe deprecated in in a future version of 3.x.

Read these as well:

- [Should I or should I not use getter and setter methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351877/should-i-or-should-i-not-use-getter-and-setter-methods)
- [Calling the variable property directly vs getter/setters - OOP Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215398/calling-the-variable-property-directly-vs-getter-setters-oop-design)